# Passing POST data by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to pass some POST data through AJAX, and i've tried everything i can think of. I'm using Google Charts EventListener to "listen" for a click (essentially an OnClick function) to process AJAX. It processes all the way through, but it does not fill the POST variable. I know that the variable "topping" does return the correct value i am looking for, using alert to ensure that. Examples of those values include 1st, 2nd, Midnight.

```
var topping = groupcol.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: { 'shifts' : topping },
      success: function(){
        alert('Works');
        window.location.reload();
            }
    });
```

At the top of the page (and bottom, for testing's sake), i have a simple statement to either print the value or "nothing." I also want to set the value to a PHP global.

```
if (isset($_POST['shifts'])) {echo "Working";}
else {echo "Nothing";}
```

It will process everything, show the "Works" alert, and reload the page, but the POST variable does not get filled. What gives?

Comment: what is the "shifts" for? just pass topping to the `data` property like so `data: topping`

Comment: also i don't see a url parameter within $.ajax? You probably need that? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @HieuLe By default, the `url` parameter is set to the current page. If he wants to post to the current page, that parameter is not needed.

Comment: I was using "shifts" to name the variable pre-POST. By using `data: topping`, how do i select that in the POST variable? And yes, the default parameter is the current page, which is exactly where i want to end up. Effectively refreshing the page, and changing a JS string to PHP global variable

Comment: just try var_dump($_POST); and see what does it gives?

Comment: This is the var_dump; `array(3) { ["nmgp_parms"]=> string(0) "" ["nmgp_outra_jan"]=> string(4) "true" ["script_case_init"]=> int(1503) }` That is after changing the code to `data: topping`

Comment: You will get a success in ajax everytime because it successfully sends the request and comes back, it has nohting to do with filling the $_POST variable.

Comment: dont change your "data" code. keep it that way only and then try.

Comment: and validate response before reloading page

Comment: No change Priya. Charlie, i'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: Do you know how to use developer tools in browsers like firefox or chrome? there you can check what kind of ajax request is actually being send and on which url and you can also view the data being posted.

Comment: `success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        window.location.reload();
            }` i.e. alert what the PHP is printing rather than a hardcoded value so you can see what's going on

Comment: also `[shifts] = $_POST['shifts']` is not valid php. What do you think `[shifts]` is???

Comment: Sorry, i was going too quickly, [shifts] is the shortcut to write a global PHP variable in Scriptcase, which is the RAD i'm using. I do know about the developers tools; both the console and `alert(data);` show the string "Midnight" being passed correctly, and my conditional fires correctly and prints "Working." `window.location.reload();` clears the POST variable again so i tried taking it out to see if it would "refresh" itself, but no dice.

Comment: The only difference I can find, on the jQuery end of things, that differs from the way I send post data is setting "dataType" to "json" and "contentType" to "application/json; charset=utf-8" in the ajax call. Might try those and see what happens.

Comment: Just tested it on my local server - this code works fine and PHP $_POST gets filled. What is before the check of the $_POST in your PHP code? Maybe you re-define the contents of $_POST somewhere?

Comment: I tried including `dataType` and `contentType` but that didn't change anything. Downloaded Firebug, and i can see the $_POST request in the console OnClick, but then the refresh clears the variable. I don't see another $_POST request clearing it, but Scriptcase has got to be clearing it, so i will look into preventing this. Thanks for the help everyone!